# Powers. Exponent set size symbol

Tags: math-mode

I need to write the following equality:

```
$| \mathbb{P}(S) | = 2^\left \{|S| \right \} $
```

How should I do so that the braces do not appear in the exponent?

Comment: `2^{|S|}` (no left and right)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Have you tried placing curly braces around the full exponent term? A more pressing question, though, is, why do you use `\left` and `\right` at all in this equation? They do absolutely nothing.

Comment: it isn't clear what output you want. don't use `\{` if you don't want braces, and you do not want left-right here, perhaps `2^{|S|}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ \left | \mathbb{P}(S) \right | = 2^{\left | S \right |} $
```

I believe that is what you are trying to get.

Or simply:

```
$ | \mathbb{P}(S) | = 2^{| S |} $
```

`\left | \right |` helps you to get symbol `|` over all your thing inside `| |`

Comment: Should those vertical bar pairs be `\lvert`...`\rvert` ?